# Windows Internet Explorer Modal dialog box preventing selenium test run

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to execute test cases in IE 8. But sometimes I am getting Windows Internet Explorer Security Warning "Do you want to enable the security content for this page" or Modal dialog box "Stop running this script...". How do I handle it in selenium Webdriver. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in `InternetExplorerOptions` which gives you the opportunity to automatically close the modal if unexpected.
This is how I handle in C# and this should be fairly similar in Java or other bindings as well.

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions { EnableNativeEvents = false };
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
//This is the main hook
options.AddAdditionalCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thanks Saifur. I couldnt resolve this issue in IE 8. But fortunately, my company stopped supporting IE 8:)